# Simple Python Webserver to save file

Tags: python-3.x, webserver

I'm trying to make a simple python webserver to save text that is `Post`ed to a file called `store.json` which is in the same folder as the python script. Here is half of my code, can someone tell me what the rest should be?

```
import string,cgi,time
from os import curdir, sep
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
#import pri

class StoreHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def do_GET(self):
    try:
        if self.path == "/store.json":
            f = open(curdir + sep + "store.json") #self.path has /test.html
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','text/json')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(f.read())
            f.close()
            return
        return
    except IOError:
        self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)
def do_POST(self):
    //if the url is 'store.json' then
    //what do I do here?

def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 80), StoreHandler)
        print 'started...'
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C received, shutting down server'
        server.socket.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As API can be called parallel so how to avoid race condition for file read/write?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's the general idea:

```
from os import curdir
from os.path import join as pjoin

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class StoreHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    store_path = pjoin(curdir, 'store.json')

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/store.json':
            with open(self.store_path) as fh:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/json')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(fh.read().encode())

    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path == '/store.json':
            length = self.headers['content-length']
            data = self.rfile.read(int(length))

            with open(self.store_path, 'w') as fh:
                fh.write(data.decode())

            self.send_response(200)


server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), StoreHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

```bsh
$ curl -X POST --data "one two three four" localhost:8080/store.json
$ curl -X GET localhost:8080/store.json    
one two three four%
```

Comment: It says `ImportError: No module named 'BaseHTTPServer'`

Comment: Ok, you need to change `from BaseHTTPServer` to `from http.server`

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the `-3.x` part of the tag.

Comment: One other thing I discovered is that you have to add `'rb'` as an argument to the open command, otherwise you get a type exception. `With open(self.store_path,'rb') as fh:`

Comment: I'm getting an exception when I try to post. `AttributeError: 'HTTPMessage' object has no attribute 'getheader'`

Comment: Ok, I changed the offending line to `self.headers['content-length']`. I also had to change the `post` `open` to `'wb'`

Comment: I think I nailed the last Python 3 issue (bytes/str) in the last edit as well.  Cheers.

Comment: To get it to work, I had to change *self.path* to *self.store_path* in the if stateent. Like this: `if self.store_path == './store.json':`

Comment: Will it also work if the uploaded file is binary? Should I open the file in such case with `'wb'` instead of `'w'`?

Comment: @SomethingSomething yes exactly. Remove the `content type` line, remove `decode()` and `encode()` and use `wb` and `rb` instead of `w` and (nothing).

Comment: Seemingly, self.end_headers() needs to be added after "self.send_response(200)" in do_POST.  Otherwise, POST request is treated as timed out.  I tested with multiple HTTP clients.

Comment: As API can be called parallel so is it safe to write file this way?

Comment: With `open(self.store_path)`, you're creating a text stream, which decodes the bytes into a string. Then with `fh.read().encode()`, you're encoding the string into bytes again. It would make more sense to use the bytes directly with `open(self.store_path, 'rb')`, then the call to `encode()` is no longer necessary.

Comment: @phil294 I'm confused by your comment. Are you suggesting to remove the `content-type` header from the `do_GET` method?

Comment: @DavidKennedy I am really sorry, I have no idea either with what I meant by that

Answer (score 11):

Important thing is that you will have to build `cgi.FieldStorage` properly from the raw posted data e.g.

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage(
            fp=self.rfile,
            headers=self.headers,
            environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                     'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                     })
```

after that it is easy to dump file, here is a simple handler which shows a form on `do_GET` to upload any file user chooses and saves that file to /tmp in `do_POST` when form is POSTed

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

import cgi

class StoreHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):

        form = cgi.FieldStorage(
            fp=self.rfile,
            headers=self.headers,
            environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                     'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                     })
        filename = form['file'].filename
        data = form['file'].file.read()
        open("/tmp/%s"%filename, "wb").write(data)

        self.respond("uploaded %s, thanks"%filename)

    def do_GET(self):
        response = """
        <html><body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <p>File: <input type="file" name="file"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
        </form>
        </body></html>
        """        

        self.respond(response)

    def respond(self, response, status=200):
        self.send_response(status)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.send_header("Content-length", len(response))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response)
```

Also note that `self.respond` is not a standard method I just added it for quickly returning some response.

Comment: this is Python 3, does SimpleHTTP still work? Sorry, I failed to mention that.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler I have changed to BaseHTTPRequestHandler if that works on   python3, also there seems to be SimplreREquestHandler in python3 http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Comment: for me after upload form['file'].file is None

Comment: As API can be called parallel so is it safe to write file this way?